# How to set Fixed Rows of Tablix in SSRS

Tags: ssrs-2008

How to do the tablix fix rows? I need to fix the report to maximum 5 rows, if record more than 5 rows will not  show . If records is only 3 record, first,second & third rows will place the data and 4 & 5 rows will leave it blank.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should achieve it in SQL query or stored proc.

However if you want to achieve it in RDL then you have to use RowNumber function in expression.Create a Row group and then restrict data set.Use expression =CEILING(RowNumber(Nothing)/5)
Please have a look at below link for your reference.

http://www.sqlchick.com/entries/2010/9/11/displaying-fixed-number-of-rows-per-ssrs-report-page.html