# SSRS Fixed Tablix/ add blank rows below

Tags: reporting-services

How to have table size fixed in SSRS?
I have tried this
[How to set Fixed Rows of Tablix in SSRS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26856855/how-to-set-fixed-rows-of-tablix-in-ssrs)
but, my concern is How to add blank rows if data row are lesser than 5, in the report where ,for example 15 rows can be fitted in. Rather than insert new rows by static, I want to display it dynamically. 
As in, we don't always know how many data rows will be there.
I can think of setting row visibility with expressions.
But, I am not quite sure and I want to understand more about it. 
Another alternate way might be using stored procedure?? I would like to know more about it too. 
I would appreciate any insight on this matter.
Thanks

Comment: Is 5 the minimum number of rows even they are empty? sorry I just want to clarify. I actually have done this using visibility.

Comment: @bot, what do you mean by that exactly? I have 5 data rows only, but inside report, the maximum row can be fitted is 15, so, how to display the rest(empty rows) ? I tried only setting ceiling..../15 but it is only not working properly.

Comment: check my answer if i did understand you

Comment: @bot, I am getting it finally. Thank u. I am alittle confused with those iif statement. So, there is no short cut way? I must set the row visibility row by row???

Comment: @Pratik I am still not successful with your approach, I don't know where I did wrong.

Comment: @ LittlBirdy I'm also looking for a shorter approach but as of now I can only think of that way. For me I don't mind doing it every rows as long as I can accomplish the task of our client.

Comment: @bot, I have one more issue, if the data rows exceed the max number of rows we define, the tablix repeat in next page, but adding those blank rows are no longer applicable, hmmmm...have u encountered this before? I think I will try out with limiting number of rows per page to get the blank rows even in consecutive pages. But haven't tried it out yet. Want to check with you first.

Comment: @ LittleBirdy i haven't because I have required max number of records to show in my table. Adding more than the max will destroy the report design. So I told our client that the max number is only 5. In my sql I also select top 5 to get only 5 records. see my updated answer

Comment: @bot, You are right. It exactly destroys the table layout if we limit the total max row number. We cannot make the table size fixed anymore. The row visibility condition setting is totally not applicable , no more blank/empty rows are added for the next report page. I have tried with =Ceiling(RowNumber(Nothing)/x) but it only limit the row number display on the page, not adding blank/empty rows below the data rows.

Comment: @bot I have tried your update too. But , as you mentioned, it is selecting only certain number of data rows, not displaying the rest which does not meet my requirements. Anyway, Thanks for helping me out buddy! Now, I can make fixed table with blank rows for my invoices alike reports which has very few data rows.

Comment: @ LittleBirdy there is another solution using sql query but I haven't tried it yet. I think its more reliable than my solution.

Comment: @bot, If you know that, can share? I did quite a number of re-search on this too. I have seen people create to add blank rows to their table by using query, they use UNION there. But I didn't go deep on it. And  I haven't tried it out too thinking that filtering in report level might be abit more easier and manageable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@bot's answer is the closet. After finding on web, I stumbled across with an article but you've got to use stored procedure(separate dataset for tablix only) which calculate out to numbers of lines/rows to fill inside the tablix, to meet your desired result. 
P.S: I don't remember the exact URL reference.

Stored procedure sample:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspPurchaseLines]
(
 --@InInvoiceNbr int
 @InLinesPerPage    int
)
AS
DECLARE @TotalRows int
DECLARE @Remainder int
DECLARE @NumPages int
DECLARE @NextPageRows int
set @TotalRows= 0
SELECT 
 ROW_NUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY P_id)as InvoiceRow,
                                             CusID,
                                             P_id,
                                             Inv_No,
                                             P_Desc,
                                             Del_date,
                                             Qty,
                                             Pack_size,
                                             U_Prize,
                                             Amt

into #tempInvoice
FROM Purchase_Details



SET @TotalRows= @@ROWCOUNT
IF @TotalRows=0
    BEGIN
        WHILE @TotalRows < @InLinesPerPage -- Add Blank Rows will generate blank invoice.
            BEGIN
                SET @TotalRows= @TotalRows+1
                INSERT  #tempInvoice
                 (InvoiceRow,
                 CusID,
                 P_id,
                 Inv_No,
                 P_Desc,
                 Del_date,
                 Qty,
                 Pack_size,
                 U_Prize,
                 Amt
                 )
                 VALUES 
                 (@TotalRows
                 --,@InInvoiceNbr
                 ,''
                 ,''
                 ,0
                 ,''
                 ,NULL
                 ,0
                 ,''
                 ,0
                 ,0
                 )
            END
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @Remainder =  @TotalRows%@InLinesPerPage -- get remainder
        IF @Remainder !=0 
        BEGIN
            -- Get the current page increase by 1 becasue we have a remainder.
            SET @NumPages = @TotalRows/@InLinesPerPage  +1 
            SET @NextPageRows = @NumPages * @InLinesPerPage
            WHILE @TotalRows < @NextPageRows -- Add Blank Rows
            BEGIN
                SET @TotalRows= @TotalRows+1
                INSERT  #tempInvoice
                (InvoiceRow,
                 CusID,
                 P_id,
                 Inv_No,
                 P_Desc,
                 Del_date,
                 Qty,
                 Pack_size,
                 U_Prize,
                 Amt
                )
                VALUES 
                (@TotalRows
                --,@InInvoiceNbr
                ,''
                ,''
                ,0
                ,NULL
                ,''
                ,0
                ,''
                ,0
                ,0
                )
            END
        END
    END
SELECT * from #tempInvoice order by InvoiceRow asc
return
```

Comment: you don't need a store procedure for row number and pag number... just use two ROW_NUMBER functions... one for count the row and other to calculate the row number over the page (use ROW_NUMBER with PARTITION)

Comment: @RobertoCorreia okay, different approach, It will be so much better if no sp is involved for this workaround. I will give it a try Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

In this answer the max row is 5 because 15 to a bit long and the number of data rows is 3.

**Target output:**

*I only have 3 data so the remaining other two rows should be empty because the max row is 5

[image]

**Solution:**
1. First create a table. Add header/column name if needed. 
2. Reference your dataset on the table(right click on the top left most of the table then select Tablix Properties)
[image]

3. Under General select Dataset Name dropdown of the dataset that you need then click OK.
4. On the data row add the data you need in just the normal way to add

[image]

5. Now on the left most of the data row right click > Insert Row > Outside Group Below.

[image]

6. Do this 5 times. This is the target output.
   [image]
7. Now on the first row of the outside of the group. On the left most right click > Row Visibility. On the expression add this.

[image]

8. Do this also on the other outer row but the values should be:

=IIF(CountRows() < 3, False, True) -> for the second row 
=IIF(CountRows() < 4, False, True) -> for the third row 
=IIF(CountRows() < 5, False, True) -> for the fourth row 
=IIF(CountRows() < 6, False, True) -> for the fifth row

*The visibility will hide the row outside the group depending on the count of rows in that group. With this even if you have empty dataset the default number of rows is always 5.In your case you add 15 blank rows outside the group with the same height in the row with data and add visibility condition for each.

**UPDATE:**
To limit the number of data to show in your table this is how I did it.

- The easiest way is to use `SELECT TOP 5` or 15 in your case in your sql query to make sure you always get the exact number of records to show in your table.

The other way is to use filter in your table.

1. I added RowCount column in my sql query to count all the number of records that I have.
2. On your report right click on the upper left corner of your table > Tablix Properties > Filters
3. Then I entered this value to limit the number of data to be shown in my table.

[image]

From this hopefully you will now have an idea how to do it in your report.

Comment: if max row per page is 10 rows. but Database has 100 rows. That 's mean I must add row in tablix 100 time  for each page until tenth page, alright?

Answer (score 0):

I used to apply logic of adding additional rows where Invoices or Letters are needed to be designed and should always span to complete page irrespective of detail lines. However, I soon changed my approach due to various issues. If you are also in the process of creating letter or invoice, read on; I don't fix table size, however I fix report layout. This way even if there are less number of rows or more rows, SSRS handles data properly. Explanation is as given below,

Let's assume that you are creating a letter with width 8.5 inch and height 11 inch. Assuming you have left 0.25 inch of border from all side; that leaves you with 8 inch of body width and 10.5 inch of height. Leave 1.5 inch for page header and 1 inch for page footer from 10.5 inch height. That leaves you with 8 inch of body height. Explicitly fix the height of Body to 8 inch. Once this is done, SSRS understands that it has to generate a page of 10.5 inch irrespective of detail lines coming from table placed in body. I hope this helps. Cheers!

P.S. This approach will only give expected results only on PDF output.

Comment: thank you for sharing your approach. I will give it a try and let you know.

Comment: I have tried your approach, but I want to display the blank rows below regardless of number of the datarows. Now, it stops after the data rows. Thus why I want report layout/table fixed.  Is there anyway I can add blank rows dynamically?

Comment: SSRS has two different renderers for on screen output and pdf output. You won't see the effect on screen but PDF output will show you expected result. In my case usually clients are not concerned with on screen output but they expect desired pdf output of letter/invoice to be sent to their customers. Sorry, I forgot to mention this in answer. I will update my answer.

Comment: oh okay I see, I will re-run my RDL again and update you.

Comment: Can I check with you again? Because I am not quite close to get the desired result. I have header and footer set, have my data tablix in inside the body. Argh, by the way how do you fix the report body size as you mentioned ? I don't see any where I can make it fix size.

Comment: @bot, But, we always don't know how many data rows in the first place. We only know how many rows can accommodate inside.

Comment: @LittleBirdy under properties pane, select Body and then set its height and width. Give me your mail ID, I will send you sample rdlc file.

Comment: Thanks, I got your email with sample files. But I have doubt it will work for my case, because I need to put data inside the table(rows+columns) to auto run since I have quite a lot of data in my dataset.