# Add empty rows to tablix dynamically in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, sql-server-data-tools, ssdt-bi

I would like to ask around for help. How do we add empty rows to `tablix` dynamically in `SSRS`, as in I wrap the rows(including the totals) inside the list. And I want to have fixed `table` layout in every page mostly just like this: But, It has multiple set of `total rows`(sub total and `grand total` at the very end). 
Have been racking my brain quite a long time, still no answer yet. Any workaround how could I get this table layout in `SSRS` Designing level???
I prefer not to mess up with `SQL data-set`. Because I want it `dynamic`. 
Any idea?

[image]

Following is my previous similar question that I have able to solved :

[SSRS Fixed Tablix/ add blank rows below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36642141/ssrs-fixed-tablix-add-blank-rows-below)

According to bot's suggestion, I could make it work. But this time around, case is a bit complicated as the `tablix` is not having only one data-row, now it has 3 rows: `one data row`, one `subtotal` and `grand total`.

Pls help me out. Thank you all.

Comment: Have tried to create another tablix and bend it with existing one?

Comment: @bmsqldev Thanks for your response. I am going to try this. However I am having some understanding issues, Suppose we will blend with a new tablix with an existing one, to get a full table layout. How to do it exactly? Can elaborate more? I mean How should I set the row visibility or make it dynamic in height to blend in it well. Sorry I am asking so details. Pardon me I am quite new to this. 

Thanks

Comment: what is the basis for the empty rows? i mean in what condition you need to add it?

Comment: @bmsqldev Actually the condition will be the left over place after a group of rows(dynamic) deducting from the full layout of the tablix.
Am I making it confusing?